# Si un comentario no se puede editar después de unos minutos, ¿por qué sí se puede eliminar en cualquier momento?

Tags: discusión, comentarios

Una vez hice un comentario en una pregunta. Cuando lo iba a editar (debido a un error ortográfico que detecté unos minutos después) vi que el botón "editar" ya no estaba, lo cual me generó sorpresa.

Investigando un poco pude encontrar que es porque no existe un historial de cambios en los comentarios, así como en las preguntas o respuestas.

Entonces me entró la duda:

¿Por qué no se puede editar después de un tiempo pero sí se puede eliminar en cualquier momento?

Comment: Publicaciones relacionadas en [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78573/274671) y [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292238/3695983) (en inglés)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En Stack Overflow siempre se ha querido resaltar que la información importante está en las preguntas y en las respuestas. El resto es levedad.

- Las preguntas y respuestas tienen historial de revisiones, pero los comentarios no.
- Las preguntas y respuestas pueden consultarse incluso después de eliminadas, pero los comentarios no.
- Las preguntas y respuestas generan reputación, pero los comentarios no.

En definitiva, yo entiendo toda esta *incomodidad* como una manera de forzar a la gente a que no utilice los comentarios más que para lo que son: para pedir una aclaración o para añadir más información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siguiendo esta lógica, si un comentario necesita ser editado pasados los cinco minutos seguramente está saliendo de ese ámbito para entrar peligrosamente en lo que debería ser una respuesta.

Recordemos que los comentarios consumen espacio útil de la pantalla y hacen que disminuya la visibilidad de preguntas y respuestas. Por ello, borremos todo lo que ya no sea útil (borrando los propios y reportando los de los demás).

Comment: Marcaste todos los puntos más importantes. Agregaría un detalle: los comentarios están ordenados cronológicamente, por lo que es lógico que no se permita editarlos, pudiendo cambiar el contexto de un hilo de comentarios. Ejemplo: si yo puse un comentario equivocado, y alguien me corrigió, está bien que no me deje editarlo, para no sacar de contexto a lo que se comentó luego.

Answer (score 5):

Porque así son las reglas de StackOverflow. A veces hay tantos comentarios que se mueven a un chat (me ha pasado en repetidas ocasiones), ese movimiento hace que los comentarios sean eliminados, dejando una mayor claridad en el contenido.

Ahora bien, el tema de esperar unos minutos para editar el comentario puede generar una confusión en un debate de comentarios (previos a ser movidos a una sala de chat). Para evitar dicha confusión, edición desabilitada. Esto es lo que percibo, siento que tiene sentido y desconozco si es la razón fundamental del feature.

Finalmente, los comentarios pueden ser eliminados por varias razones siendo una de ellas la clarificación de contenido, tanto por parte de la gente que realiza preguntas como también por parte de aquellos usuarios que publican respuestas. Otra razón es porque el comentario se encuentra fuera de contexto.

Comment: Entiendo, pero he visto en varias respuestas y preguntas en las que el orden de comentarios no cuadra, no tiene coherencia, es como si eliminaran comentarios del medio entonces todo pierde sentido y no se entiende de que se está hablando en algunas ocasiones

Comment: para eso existe la bandera para reportar y los moderadores tienen la responsabilidad de limpiar el contenido :D Entran en modo Kira y a eliminar comentarios sin más :D

Answer (score 1):

Edición : **esta respuesta es incorrecta**, [la edición de comentarios por moderadores nunca constituye una infracción de copyright (en inglés)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302895/348498) debido a la licencia doble que se concede a SO. Y en el caso general ni siquiera es una infracción de CC-BY-SA 3.0. Pero la dejo porque saber que esto es un error también es útil y relevante a la pregunta.

---

Ya hay otra respuesta que explica bien la situación cuando un usuario edita su propio comentario. No aportaría nada repetirlo por lo que me limitaré al otro caso de ediciones de comentarios.

Un comentario sí se puede editar después de cinco minutos. Es necesario ser moderador diamantado para poder hacerlo y en ese caso también puede editar los comentarios de otra persona.

Lamentablemente cuando un moderador ejecerce esta capacidad con un comentario ajeno suceden dos cosas negativas :

- Se atribuye un comentario a una persona pese a que esa persona no escribió exáctamente ese comentario. En el comentario editado por el moderador aparece que el comentario ha sido editado pero no por quién y no hay forma de distinguirlo de un comentario editado por el autor original del comentario.
- Se infringe la licencia [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) bajo la que se publicó el comentario original. Concretamente el apartado 4c(iv)

> and (iv) , consistent with Ssection 3(b), in the case of an
>   Adaptation, a credit identifying the use of the Work in the Adaptation
>   (e.g., "French translation of the Work by Original Author," or
>   "Screenplay based on original Work by Original Author"). The credit
>   required by this Section 4(c) may be implemented in any reasonable
>   manner; provided, however, that in the case of a Adaptation or
>   Collection, at a minimum such credit will appear, if a credit for all
>   contributing authors of the Adaptation or Collection appears, then as
>   part of these credits and in a manner at least as prominent as the
>   credits for the other contributing authors. For the avoidance of
>   doubt, You may only use the credit required by this Section for the
>   purpose of attribution in the manner set out above and, by exercising
>   Your rights under this License, You may not implicitly or explicitly
>   assert or imply any connection with, sponsorship or endorsement by the
>   Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties, as appropriate,
>   of You or Your use of the Work, without the separate, express prior
>   written permission of the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution
>   Parties.

Por este motivo recomiendo a los moderadores nunca editar comentarios ajenos. Si un comentario no puede permanecer en el sitio tal y como está la alternativa es eliminarlo por completo.

Comment: Muy, muy raramente se editan comentarios ajenos. Como moderador en otro sitio, es algo que he hecho con cuentagotas y siempre para corregir alguna errata. Es un trabajo poco útil y, por el mismo hecho de que los comentarios son algo leve, se prefiere borrarlos y que el autor publique otro. Nótese de todos modos que la edición, como todo lo que hacen los moderadores, queda registrado y disponible para el resto de moderadores y empleados de SO.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, estoy de acuerdo en que podría explicitarse de alguna forma. Veo que [se propuso que se notificara](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281749/209901) y [cosas similares](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74691/209901). Pero vaya, que hablen los moderadores de [es.so], pero no creo que editar comentarios cubra más del 0,1% de su tiempo y en todos casos vendrá dado por erratas tipográficas o reportes de los propios usuarios para que algo se modifique.

Comment: @fedorqui He preguntado sobre el tema en SEmeta y he llegado a la conclusión de que estoy equivocado. La edición de comentarios por parte de moderadores nunca es una infracción de derechos de autor. Si es una edición abusiva merece ser reportada pero ni siquiera en ese caso sería una infracción de derechos de autor, solo sería un asunto interno de SO.

Comment: Interesante. Ya sería otra discusión determinar cómo un usuario puede saber que le han hecho una edición abusiva, dado que la interfaz de usuario no indica que se haya cambiado un comentario. Buena investigación, gracias.